# How to update object in array of objects

Tags: reactjs

I have following part of React code:
This is handler for adding new object item to the array.

So I am checking if object exist in whole array of objects. If yes I want to increase quantity of this object by 1. Else I want to add object and set quantity to 1.

I am getting error when I want to add 2nd same product (same id)

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property 'quantity' of object '#<Object>'
```

```js
export const Component = ({ book }: { book: Book }) => {
    const [basket, setBasket] = useRecoilState(Basket);

    const handleAddBookToBasket = () => {

        const find = basket.findIndex((product: any) => product.id === book.id)

        if (find !== -1) {
            setBasket((basket: any) => [...basket, basket[find].quantity = basket[find].quantity + 1])
        } else {
            setBasket((basket: any) => [...basket, { ...book, quantity: 1 }])
        }
    }
```

EDIT:

```js
if (find !== -1) {
  setBasket((basket: any) =>
    basket.map((product: any) => ({
      ...product,
      quantity: product.quantity + 1,
    }))
  );
} else {
  setBasket((basket: any) => [...basket, { ...book, quantity: 1 }]);
}
```

Comment: `setBasket((basket) => basket.map((product) => /* pass through original or create new one */))`?

Comment: I update my code and post. Is that correct? @jonrsharpe

Comment: Well does it _work_?!

Comment: I need to update quantity of current book, not to all of them

Comment: Then why do you not have some sort of _condition_ to check whether this is a product you need to update or not?

Answer (score 0):

**data structures**

I'd say the root of your "problem" is that you chose the wrong data structure for your basket. Using `Array<Item>` means each time you need to update a specific item, you have to perform *O(n)* linear search.

If you change the basket to `{ [ItemId]: Item }` you can perform instant *O(1)* updates. See this complete example below. Click on some products to add them to your basket. Check the updated basket quantity in the output.

```js
function App({ products = [] }) {
  const [basket, setBasket] = React.useState({})
  function addToBasket(product) {
    return event => setBasket({
      ...basket,
      [product.id]: {
        ...product,
        quantity: basket[product.id] == null
          ? 1
          : basket[product.id].quantity + 1
      }
    })
  }
  return <div>
    {products.map((p, key) =>
      <button key={key} onClick={addToBasket(p)} children={p.name} />
    )}
    <pre>{JSON.stringify(basket, null, 2)}</pre>
  </div>
}

const products = [
  { id: 1, name: "ginger" },
  { id: 2, name: "garlic" },
  { id: 3, name: "turmeric" }
]

ReactDOM.render(<App products={products}/>, document.querySelector("#app"))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.14.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.14.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

**object update**

As a good practice, you can make a function for immutable object updates.

```js
// Obj.js

const update = (o, key, func) =>
    ({ ...o, [key]: func(o[key]) })

export { update }
```

Then `import` it where this behavior is needed. Notice it's possible to use on nested object updates as well.

```js
// App.js

import * as Obj from "./Obj"

function App({ products = [] }) {
  // ...
  function addToBasket(product) {
    return event => setBasket(
      Obj.update(basket, product.id, (p = product) =>  // ✅
        Obj.update(p, "quantity", (n = 0) => n + 1)    // ✅
      )
    )
  }
  // ...
}
```

**object remove**

You can use a similar technique to `remove` an item from the basket. Instead of coupling the behavior directly in the component that needs removal, add it to the `Obj` module.

```js
// Obj.js

const update = (o, key, func) =>
    ({ ...o, [key]: func(o[key]) })

const remove: (o, key) => { // ✅
  const r = { ...o }
  delete r[key]
  return r
}

export { update, remove } // ✅
```

Now you can `import` the `remove` behaviour in any component that needs it.

```js
function App() {
  const [basket, setBasket] = React.useState({
    1: { id: 1, name: "ginger", quantity: 5 },
    2: { id: 2, name: "garlic", quantity: 6 },
    3: { id: 3, name: "tumeric", quantity: 7 },
  })
  function removeFromBasket(product) {
    return event => {
      setBasket(
        Obj.remove(basket, product.id) // ✅
      )
    }
  }
  return <div>
    {Object.values(basket).map((p, key) =>
      <div key={key}>
        {p.name} ({p.quantity})
        <button onClick={removeFromBasket(p)} children="❌" />
      </div>
    )}
    <pre>{JSON.stringify(basket, null, 2)}</pre>
  </div>
}

// inline module for demo
const Obj = {
  remove: (o, key) => {
    const r = {...o}
    delete r[key]
    return r
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.querySelector("#app"))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.14.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.14.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

Answer (score -1):

In your `setBasket` your should create a new object instead of updating current one

your code should look like these one :

```
{...basket, ...{
quantity : basket.quantity + 1
}}
```

Comment: I don't get it ;/

Comment: Let me look to your changes and I back to you :)

Comment: can you add your basket structure. I'm not able to know if you have a list of products inside or not ( based on your edit )

Comment: Problem is solved, thanks for showing interest

Comment: No problem. Don't forget to add the answer for the other users :)